# Expression en un "Tournemain" ou "Tour de main"?

Tags: expressions, québec

Je croyais toujours avoir entendu l'expression :

> J'ai fait ceci en un **tour de main** [...]

Mais voilà qu'aujourd'hui j'ai entendu :

> [Bricolez un piège à moustique en un **tournemain** | Source: Météomedia](http://www.meteomedia.com/videos/Galerie/qc/video_gallery/bricolez-un-pige-moustiques-en-un-tournemain/2312993039001/2312993039001_0)

En « googlant », je me suis rendu compte que Tournemain existait mais, est-ce moi qui me suis toujours trompé dans ce que j'entendais et employais ou est-ce tout simplement que les deux expressions existent et veulent en fait dire la même chose?

À titre de référence pour les anglophones, j'ai aussi trouvé une source mentionnant que cela provenait d'une déformation d'une expression anglaise: [En un tour de main](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/198/en-un-tour-de-main/), expression anglaise étant probablement: [knack](https://translate.google.com/#fr/en/tour%20de%20main) même si l'expression ne peut-être traduite mot-pour-mot.

Comment: Et s'il y a lieu, laquelle des deux expressions devraient être préférée?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux expriment la rapidité d'exécution : le temps que la main soit [re]tournée, *tournemain*,  ou qu'elle fasse un tour *tour de main*.

Il n'y a pas de préférence à avoir, *tournemain* est plus soutenu, *tour de main* serait plus entendu dans l'artisanat ou les métiers techniques, mais ils sont parfaitement interchangeables.

---

Avoir le *tour de main*, c'est avoir acquis une habileté particulière dans sa discipline, c'est aussi exécuter avec célérité son ouvrage, cette expression a donc  deux significations.

... que n'a pas *tournemain* qui signifie "En un instant".

Comment: Intéressant votre deuxième point. Je n'avais jamais réalisé que l'on en faisait cette utilisation, vous avez raison.